# How can I fix this warning produced when I run my Test::Unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm getting this warning in my Test::Unit output...

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rtest/unit -e "%w[test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
Loaded suite -e
Started
.../Users/ethan/project/mtc/contactdb/app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:30: warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.8/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:142
[...repeated eight times...]
```

I think the relevant part is:

```
/contactdb/app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:30: warning: 
  multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
```

Looking at my Haml file, I've narrowed it down to this snippet (I think)...

```
- form_tag( recover_login_path, :method => 'get') do |f|
  %p
    = text_field_tag :email, '', { :size => '35', :maxlength => '255' }
```

`recover_login` is a named route.

I looked at the API docs for `form_tag`. It seems like my code is following what they have in the examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `form_tag` block takes no parameters. So remove the `|f|` and the warning should go away.

Comment: Right solution, but for the wrong reason. The other response is the technically correct one.

Answer (score 6):

`form_tag` only passes in the form builder object `|f|` when you use a model object with it.

```
form_tag @user, :method => :get do |f|
  f.text_field :first_name
end
```

But constructing your own form path with no passed in model object, the block argument is not passed in or used.

```
form_tag user_path(@user.id), :method => :get do
  text_field :user, :first_name
end
```